# How to pass data from a control to another control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp Literal element that I want to pass to an object control to set its data property so that it pulls a filename from a database. Here's what I got:

```
<asp:FormView ID="Formview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data='<%= strFileName %>'
        width="450" height="380">
        <!-- this param is required for anyone using IE--><param name="src" value='<%= Filename %>' />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
    </object>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

code behind:

```
Partial Class VideoPlayer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected strFileName As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim vidID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("ID"))

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|/webvideos.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID=" & vidID
    strFileName = "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename")

    con.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Any idea? I hope it is simple, lol.

Comment: The "visible=false" make it not render at all. Use some css to hide it, but first test it without visible=false to see if works.

Comment: @Aristos If I make it visible, it just shows up on my webpage. That let's me know the value is being stored in the Literal element, but it still doesn't explain how to set the data property of the object element to the value of the literal.

Comment: and I don't want the literal to actually show up on my page. I just want to use it to store a value and then set the data property to that value

Comment: Are you still having issue with this or resolved with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581879/using-eval-function-in-my-code-behind/21584667#21584667

Answer (score 1):

I've not dealt with the "percent pound" databind tags, but you may be able to do this:

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data='<%# "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename") %>'
        width="450" height="380">
        <!-- this param is required for anyone using IE-->
        <param name="src" value='<%# "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename") %>' />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
    </object>
```

If not - you can load your filename + path into a protected global-scope variable (e.g. `strFilepath`) on the server side in the page load, or declare a protected function that returns the filename + path (which you may want to cache if you are going to be calling it a lot) - then do it like so:

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data='<%= getFilepath() %>'
            width="450" height="380">
            <!-- this param is required for anyone using IE-->
            <param name="src" value='<%= getFilepath() %>' />
            <param name="autostart" value="false" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
        </object>
```

and then something like this in the code behind:

```
Protected Function getFilepath() As String    
  Return "file path/filename"
End Sub
```

or

```
Protected Dim strFilepath As String
Public Sub Page_Load()
    strFilePath = "file path/filename"
End Sub
```

along with `<%= strFilepath %>`

make sense?

Comment: Okay, so how do I set that variable in the code behind? I've got something that resembles something like that in my updated question.

Comment: Also, the top answer is how I originally tried to do it, but learned that the object element is not a databound control

Comment: it keeps telling me the strFilePath hasn't been declared or inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: It needs to be public or protected (I think protected should work), and also not declared in the page_load, just set there.  As an alternative, see the updates in my answer.  Instead of pointing to strFilePath you can simply call a function that will return the string..  Lots of ways you can do it.

Comment: How do I return the string in the code behind that is in a database? Also, I set the string to a hard coded value and it is still telling that the getFilePath is not accessible error.

Comment: What I'd do is query the database (you may be able to still use your literal if you fear working with the database directly ;) ).  You probably need to rebuild the code behind for the other page to clear the not accessible error/warning.  If you still get the not accessible, then set it to Public instead of Protected.  If you still get it, try closing the file you're working with and re-opening it.  AFAIK Protected should work.

Comment: I used the second answer you posted about declaring the variable globally and then in the Page_Load event, hardcoding it and it worked. So in the page load event, can I set it equal to the Literal element also?

Comment: The reason i ask it that way is because I'm trying to use the least amount of code possible. Keep it clean and such, you know what I mean?

Comment: If you want to leverage your literal element with databinding, I don't see why it wouldn't work.  The only issue you may encounter is the order in which the databinding and the page_load occur.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx .  If the value you expect to be there in the literal's text is not there during the page_load, you may need to look at setting the variable sometime after the initial data binding occurs and before the <%= strFilepath %> gets resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
 <asp:Literal ID="VidPath1" runat="server" Text='<%# "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename") %>' Visible="false" />

    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data='<%# me.VidPath1.Text %>'
        width="450" height="380">
        <!-- this param is required for anyone using IE-->
        <param name="src" value='<%# me.VidPath1.Text %>' />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
    </object>
```

Edit:

Tested the below code, it works.

```
<asp:Literal ID="VidPath1" runat="server" Text="Test Me Literal" Visible="true" />
<asp:Label Text='<%# me.VidPath1.Text %>' runat="server" /></p>
```

Please try with a label, see if it gets proper value. If yes, then possibly you need to correct the path if it doesn't work.

**Edit2:**

The .vb part:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        DataBind()

    End Sub
End Class
```

The designer part:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead"> 
            <asp:Literal ID="VidPath1" runat="server" Text="Test Me Literal" Visible="true" />
            <asp:Label Text='<%# me.VidPath1.Text %>' runat="server" /></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It is VB, so it needs to be &. What about the data property? That's kinda the main thing, right?

Comment: Ok. Never worked with VB. ;). Same with the data property also. You can copy paste the same. I'm updating the answer. Does it work?

Comment: Tells me that VIdPath hasn't been declared.

Comment: Try placing this before the VidPath1.Text

Comment: this.VidPath1.Text ??

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand it either. Am I missing something elsewhere in my code?

Comment: You need to write DataBind() in page load. But it should work. I tested it in C#.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but do I just write Databind()?

Comment: Yes and use me instead of this. Updating the answer.

Comment: Okay, I found that instead of "this" it should be "Me" for VB.net. But now it is telling me VidPath1 is not a member of ASP.videoplayer_aspx

Comment: Change Visible="true" for now and check again.

Comment: Relax, we will find a solution. M also kinda new to this. Did you tried displaying the value in the label?

Comment: I looked at this page http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/191553/ERROR-it-is-not-a-member-of-ASP-default_aspx and found that it may be an error with my top line of code. It keeps telling me there is an expression expected.

Comment: You know, the "<%@ Page Title="Your video is now playing" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="VideoPlayer.aspx.vb" Inherits="VideoPlayer" %>" line of code.

Comment: Set AutoEventWireup="true".

Comment: Now instead of "expression expected" it gives me the Vidpath1 is not a member error again. I really appreciate your help on this. You must really want the 50! lol

Comment: Not really! Just wanted to help you out. Thought i can, so was trying to help you out.

Comment: Yeah, so when i hover over the blue squiggly, it gives me the "VidPath1 is not a member" error

Comment: Check your mark up with mine. I'm posting it in edit.

Comment: Even that doesn't work than please try creating a fresh new page and implementing the concept with Literal and Label controls.

Comment: Okay, it seems like we may still be dealing with not being able to use <% %> in the data property of the object control. It works with the asp Label, but we've still not gotten it to work with the object control

Comment: Did you give up on me Ashish?

Comment: Yes. It worked. Are you getting an error or the video isn't displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you extract the `<object>` element out of that data bound template and put it just by itself you should be able to do as follows:

The property (VideoPath) is assigned the path, then you can bind that value anywhere you want (bar maybe in templated controls like you have in your example)

Please note that the 'Literal' control part of you question is a little vague. Do you mean you want to display the path in the literal also? Can you please show in your example how it would be represented. Cheers.

**Warning**: Rusty VB here.. hopefully it is correct.

```
Partial Class VideoPlayer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected strFileName As String

Protected Property VideoPath as String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim vidID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("ID"))

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|/webvideos.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID=" & vidID

    VideoPath = "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename")

    con.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

You can use <%= VideoPath %> then to bind the string wherever you want

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data='<%= VideoPath  %>'
    width="450" height="380">
    <!-- this param is required for anyone using IE-->
    <param name="src" value='<%= VideoPath %>' />
    <param name="autostart" value="false" />
    <param name="controller" value="true" />
</object>
```

Alternativley you should be able to add runat="server" on those tags I would think without any issue (i.e. both the object and param elements) and assign the correct attributes the value in server side code)