# Using Eval function in my code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here's my code:

```
Partial Class VideoPlayer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected strFileName As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim vidID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("ID"))

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|/webvideos.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID=" & vidID
    strFileName = "videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename")

    con.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

So when I run the code, it tells me it can't run Eval on my string. What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you want to get "Filename" from? I don't see it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Global variable, forgot to add it up there.

Comment: How do you declare it? Why don't you call it directly?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468300/how-to-pass-data-from-a-control-to-another-control) for what I'm trying to do. I've got it almost done, I just need to figure out how to get strFileName to equal the string plus the string from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval will work in your .aspx code with a DataBoundControl.

When in code-behind, you are setting up the connectionstring, sql query and other variables but you are not actually executing the query.

So your code should be something like below:

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim vidID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("ID"))

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|/webvideos.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID=" & vidID

    //Create an OleDbCommand object.
    //Pass in the SQL query and the OleDbConnection object
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, con)

    //Execute the command 
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader 

    //Read the first record from the reader
    reader.Read()
    strFileName = "videos\TrainingVideos\" & reader(1)
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Hey @gbs! You are the man! A datareader eh? So good to finally get this resolved. I had to change your answer just a bit because the Read method just moves to the next record. Also, the DataReader object is an array as well, so when I did reader(1), it grabbed the second field in my record. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First the most important, you are open for sql-injection here:

```
"SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID=" & vidID
```

Use sql-parameters instead.

You can use `Eval` only in a databinding context. So you need to call `Me.DataBind` before.

```
Me.DataBind()
Dim fileName = Me.Eval("Filename").ToString()
strFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine("videos/TrainingVideos", fileName)
```

However, i don't know what you're actually trying to achieve here. Why do you need it at all?

> Global variable, forgot to add it up there.

Then access it directly.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468300/how-to-pass-data-from-a-control-to-another-control)

Comment: I ended up trying to use the idea suggested by mikey

Comment: I had not. That's actually exactly what I'm trying to do though, I thought. I'm trying to set a variable to the string from the database and then reference the variable in my aspx page.

Comment: By the way, I used your code and it still is giving me the error that it can't use Eval on string.

Comment: @Joseph: i still don't understand why you need `Eval` at all. Why don't you assign `strFileName` the value from your database directly. Then you could use the approach of above link to assign it to the object tag via `data="<%= strFileName %>"`

Comment: The structure of the website is that a user is on one page, say word.aspx, and there is a gridview of links generated from a database. They click on one of the links and then, depending on which link they click, it takes them to videoplayer.aspx?ID="ID of record in database they clicked on in the gridview on word.aspx" I need to be able to take the ID and grab the relevant filename.